# How to find top n common elements in a list?

Tags: r, list

I am relatively new to R and I am trying to find the top 3 elements in the data frame in a list. For example, I have a list like this

```
Combined <- list(L1 <- mtcars[1:6,], 
                 L2 <- mtcars[2:7,],
                 L3 <- mtcars[3:8,],
                 L4 <- mtcars[4:9,],
                 L5 <- mtcars[5:10,])
```

I aim to return the top 3 common rownames in decreasing order, like

```
[1] "Hornet Sportabout"    "Valiant"     "Duster 360"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what is desired. You are gathering the rownames of those list items, tabulating and sorting.

```
sort( table( c( sapply(Combined, rownames) ) ),
      decreasing=TRUE ) [1:3]
#---------------------------
Hornet Sportabout           Valiant        Duster 360 
                5                 5                 4
```

If you just want the character values then wrap `names` around that result.

```
names( sort( table( c( sapply(Combined, rownames) ) ), 
             decreasing=TRUE ) [1:3] )
#[1] "Hornet Sportabout" "Valiant"           "Duster 360"
```

Comment: Just for completeness, what if the data frames in the `list` have different lengths?

Comment: The `sapply` function returns a list if the results are not of the same length. You can use `unlist` instead of `c`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new column with rownames in each list, combine them in one dataframe, `count` each rownames and return top 3.

```
library(dplyr)

purrr::map_df(Combined, tibble::rownames_to_column) %>%
  count(rowname) %>%
  slice_max(n = 3, n, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  pull(rowname)

#[1] "Hornet Sportabout" "Valiant"           "Duster 360"
```